# FB.login only works with my developers account

Tags: javascript, authentication, sdk, localhost, facebook-login

When I use the `FB.login` function from the JavaScript SDK and I am logged in on Facebook with my developer account the popup appear and everything is fine. If I'm logged out or logged in with another account the page won't load and gives me an error

> `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`

In my app settings the sandbox mode is off so this shouldn't happen right?
I am hosting my website locally, don't know if it matters.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same error just now popped up for us. Resolved it:

We found we still had a Facebook SDK API Key in some of our configuration which was being used for some of our log-in screens.
If you're still using an API key with your javascript SDK, try using your app ID instead. You can find that in the settings for your app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps